# ABSOLUTE necessity of particle に in "topic marker" には

Tags: translation, particle-に, particle-は

"This store has all sorts of bags": この店**は**鞄が色々あります should be a good translation and a natural sentence, which is different from "There are all sorts of bags in this store": この店**には**鞄が色々あります.

**The Question**: I would like verification that even without に the two English translations can be acceptable, because "There are [...] in this store" conveys the same meaning as "This store has [...]"

[this is not based on translation style-preference, i.e., literal, paraphrase, *verbum pro verbo*, etc., but a grammatical question in re: absolute necessity of に in the topic marker "には" and semantic equivalence of the 2 proposed English translations]

thank you in advance for your time and attention in this matter!

Comment: Hum, I don't think the two sentences are 100% equivalent in English or Japanese. For example, consider eBay.... eBay has lots of bags, yet there are no bags in eBay.

Comment: @Ragaroni "yes, but..." (1) your example diverges from a physical place, such as store; (2a) strictly speaking, eBay doesn't 'have' bags, but the owners of the bags do -- presumably "in" a place: house, garage, closet (2b) to be fair, your point is correct here, too, "the closet" does not "have"; (3) casuistry clarifies by excluding the liminal, but the question remains unanswered: Thanks, but please offer an answer to the question.

Comment: I think part of @Ragaroni's point is not casuistry, but rather pointing out that your question presupposes a faulty premise.  And given that faulty premise, your question isn't really answerable.

Comment: Put another way, この店は expresses a topic of この店 ("this store"), whereas この店には has a topic of この店に ("in this store").  The first topic ≠ the second topic: not semantically equivalent, in either language.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Tyvm!! your comment (re-)indicates, as I stated, the literal meaning of the 2 Japanese versions as reflected in the 2 English sentences. However, the question remains unanswered: "even without に the two English translations can be acceptable". hope this clarifies :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking.  From the body of your question, I disagree with your statement that _"There are [...] in this store" conveys the same meaning as "This store has [...]"_.  Strictly speaking, these are separate statements.  That said, translation is a squishy pursuit.  Depending on context and tone and what effect you (as the translator) are attempting to impart, translating without the "in" in the English should be fine -- that is, translating この店には～ある as "the store has ~" instead of "in the store, there is/are ~".

Comment: thanks again! (1) your disagreement would sometimes apply to non-merchandise, but not applicable to 'things-to-buy" (2) you also verify the equivalence. (3) i still wonder about the specific grammar